# Converting stanfordNLP parse tree into DOT format

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there a way/method to convert the parse tree generated by stanford parser into DOT format. I'm aware of the method toDotFormat() that converts stanford dependency output to DOT. But I want to convert edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree to DOT.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no code to do this. But you could write such a method by walking down through the children of a tree yourself.

Comment: thanks prof. manning. actually what i wanted was to convert from penn treebank format to dot. but then i found PennTreeReader class and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive method for generating the desired result.

The function uses Breadth-first Search to traverse the tree.

https://github.com/skrtbhtngr/corenlp-helper/blob/master/TreeExtended.java